# meaning(metaphor) of the sentence: "putting my fireproof suit on"

Tags: metaphors

I saw the Q&A few weeks ago,

A: Are you watching the walking dead
B: No."putting my fireproof suit on"

so, does it mean afraid or angry or something?

THANK YOU :)

Comment: It means he knows he's going to get flamed for saying that;  who in their right mind wouldn't be watching TWD?

Comment: @Jim * finishes zipping up and folding Velcro flap of flame suit * I won't be. The last truly good reason to watch a film or TV show with zombies in it was *Shaun of the Dead*.

Comment: @pyobum- yeah, me either.  I watched it for a while, but got busy and stopped and realized I didn't really miss it.

Comment: @Jim: Who in their right mind doesn't have better things to do than watch TV?

Comment: @Jim "I watched it for a while, but got busy and stopped and realized I didn't really miss it." That actually perfectly describes how I feel about television in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an internet slang type of thing.

The Walking Dead is a popular show. Person B thinks they will be insulted because they aren't watching this show.

A slang term for insulting someone is "burning" them (also, "flaming").

Person B thinks they will be insulted. Person B thinks they will be "burned".

A fireproof suit is something firefighters wear to protect them from being burned in a fire.

As a joke, Person B is saying they are putting on a fireproof suit, to protect themselves from the burns (insults) that are coming.